# How to decide the size of image for spectrogram based on audio length

Tags: audio, librosa, fast-ai

I am following the fastai audio classification using images tutorial [1](https://github.com/etown/dl1). The image size is 230x224 for URBANSOUND dataset which has length of 4 seconds. I am using DCASE audio dataset which has length of 10 seconds. So, how is the size of image is decided in librosa based on the length of audio?

Following is code for spectogram generation.

```
def create_fold_spectrograms(fold):
    spectrogram_path = Path('spectrogram/')  
    audio_path = Path('audio/')  
    print(f'Processing fold {fold}')
    os.mkdir(spectrogram_path/fold)
    for audio_file in list(Path(audio_path/f'{fold}').glob('*.wav')):
        samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(audio_file)
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=[0.72,0.72])
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.set_frame_on(False)
        filename  = spectrogram_path/fold/Path(audio_file).name.replace('.wav','.png')
        filename = (str(filename))
        S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=samples, sr=sample_rate)
        librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=np.max))
        plt.savefig(filename, dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0)
        plt.close('all')
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating a spectrogram with librosa, you essentially chop the audio (1d data) into overlapping segments and compute the frequency contents for each of these segments.

The length of each segment is determined by the `n_fft` parameter to the [melspectrogram](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html) call. How much two subsequent segments overlap depends on the `hop_length` parameter. By default librosa uses `n_fft=2048` and `hop_length=512`, so there is a 75% overlap between subsequent segments.

Note that these segments are often referred to a as *frames*.

Your question boils down to how many frames (length of the image) you get for a given length of audio.

Let's assume you have `N=10s` of audio. That means you have `N * sample_rate` samples. With a `hop_length` of 512 you get roughly (this also depends on padding and your `n_fft`) `(N * sample_rate) / hop_length` frames.

So for your 10s, you get roughly 430 frames, because by default librosa uses a sample rate of 22050 Hz.

The height, i.e., your frequency resolution, only depends on the number of mel bands you decide to use. You can manipulate it by passing the `n_mels` parameter to the `melspectrogram` function.